# Multiplayer game to demo Wi-fi

Tags: javascript, multiplayer, wifi

So in Germany we have built up a huge Wi-fi system and usually you have to login to the system to surf the web. As a gimik we want to add a multiplayer game so without having to pay for usual internet they can play a webbased multiplayer game. What multiplayer games do you know. It just has to be 2 player really. I would want to program it with JavaScript since I am uncapable of doing Flash.

Any good ideas? 
Maybe even a finished game I could use?

I would want it to be an instant game so no browser game where you would have to check back every 5 hours or so.

Answer (score 4):

How about something like [Tanks](http://www.mathsisfun.com/games/tanks.html) ?  Or maybe something along the lines of [BattleShip](http://www.sinkmyship.com/) ?

Of if maybe you don't want an action game, how about trying a Card Game like [Poker](http://gpokr.com/#Dodge)?

---

Take a look at [this page](http://metalab.at/wiki/JavaScript_game_development) which is dedicated specifically to JavaScript Game Development, and also [here](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/25-amazing-javascript-games-some-fun-and-inspiration/) in where they list 25 JavaScript games

And I also suggest you take a look at [Canvas Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Canvas_tutorial) to implement a smooth-graphics, JavaScript-controlled game.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any specific games to add to Dreas Grech's suggestions, but I would recommend that you choose a game with a relatively simple (but not too simple, of course) set of player strategies so that you'll be able to also implement an AI/bot to play against any users who aren't able to find human opponents.